# Best practice to handle React callbacks when passing to as prop to component

Tags: reactjs

Considering two examples below:

**Example 1**. Here I am passing ***handleNameClick*** function and name as a props to child component and handling click on button inside child component calling passed function with name prop.

```
const ChildComponent = ({ name, onClick }) => {
    const handleClick = useCallback(() => onClick(name), [name, onClick]);
    return <button onClick={handleClick}>{name}</button>;
};

const ParentComponent = ({ names, handleNameClick }) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {names.map(name => (
                <ChildComponent key={name} name={name} onClick={handleNameClick} />
            ))}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

**Example 2**. Here I am passing anonymous callback function as property and calling it once button is clicked inside child component.

```
const ChildComponent = ({ name, onClick }) => {
    return <button onClick={onClick}>{name}</button>;
};

const ParentComponent = ({ names, handleNameClick }) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {names.map(name => (
                <ChildComponent key={name} name={name} onClick={() => handleNameClick(name)} />
            ))}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

Are there any advantages/disadvantages or best practices of using either technique?
From readability side it looks like excessive props drilling in first example, because I pass callback function to child component just for sake of calling it with name argument that is also accessible outside child component and can be called as in second example. But from the other side I use useCallback hook (in this scenario there are not a lot of performance cost) to pass it button click event. Maybe using React.memo on child component would make more sense in first example, but memo still compares properties as well as useCallback hook, so there are no big difference.

So in this case is it just pure preference and readability consideration or there are more under the hood?

Answer (score 0):

> From readability side it looks like excessive props drilling in first example, because I pass callback function to child component just for sake of calling it with name argument that is also accessible outside child component and can be called as in second example.

In your second example this is OK since there *is* extra information being transmitted in that the parent now knows *what* item was clicked, and not just the set of items that is being passed down. This is, in and of itself, more info and useful as long as the thing above `ParentComponent` needs that.

In your first example, you are right, it doesn't need to pass name upwards as the context is known by the parent.

So your second example is therefore preferred in my opinion. But really, your question relates to where the concerns of the thing in question should live -- which often depends on the use case.

> But from the other side I use useCallback hook (in this scenario there are not a lot of performance cost) to pass it button click event. Maybe using React.memo on child component would make more sense in first example, but memo still compares properties as well as useCallback hook, so there are no big difference.

You can `useCallback` just as well in your second example as well so this question is separate from your first one. You'd usually `useCallback` over `memo`, which is generally an older method. The thing with `memo` is that the parent component of the one that is memoized, can't configure that memoization as it sees fit. The `memo` component has decided for you. In the `useCallback`/hook pattern, the consumer can decide what to memoize at will and how, which is generally better.

Unless you component has expensive rerenders, you don't even need it (like in this example). In your example rerenders are almost free. Remember, the memoization itself has a small cost too.

But at this point we're splitting hairs. Your second example is correct and fine.

Comment: Can you advise how to use useCallaback in second example? Can I use it in return statement? I can not use it outside of render as name is only known from array when iterating in return statement.